# Convert linq to c#

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to linq and having difficulty to translate from linq to c#.

```
private static char[] createCharArray(int length, char defaultChar)
{
    return (from c in new char[length] select defaultChar).ToArray();
}
```

any help please?

Comment: LINQ *is* C#, what is it you want to do exactly?

Comment: What is `defaultChar` is it `default(char)` or some `defaultChar` defined in your code

Comment: I am translating an application working with linq to Java. I cant understand exactly what is happening over here :/

Comment: just use a for loop to go through the array

Comment: In addition to Jeroen's point, you don't even have compilable C# code there.

Comment: what you have written seems neither c# nor linq

Comment: @user3237553: can you make up your mind and just edit all the code at once? And add some formatting yourself while you're at it.

Comment: Just keep the program written in C#. It's probably better off that way.

Comment: poor guy. It can be rough around here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to create a `char[]` (array) of a given length and pre-fill it with a specified character. If that is the case then the code you have already is perfectly valid C#, so you don't need to change anything.

Personally, I would prefer to use the following LINQ:

```
private static char[] createCharArray(int length, char defaultChar) 
{ 
    return Enumerable.Repeat(defaultChar, length).ToArray(); 
}
```

---

If however, your question is about converting a LINQ statement to a non-LINQ version, because for whatever reason you cannot use LINQ, then you can use a simple `for` loop:

```
private static char[] createCharArray(int length, char defaultChar) 
{ 
    char[] result = new char[length];
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        result[i] = defaultChar;
    } 
    return result;
}
```

---

**NOTE**: As a word of warning, function names in C# typically start with uppercase by convention, i.e. `CreateCharArray`

Answer (score 2):

First LINQ is C#. What your code is doing is,

It is creating an array of characters with all elements set to default character.

So if you have specified `length = 10` you will get a character array of `10` elements with all array elements set to `defaultChar`.

It is same as:

```
char defaultChar = 'A';
int length = 10;
char[] charArray = new char[length];
for (int i = 0; i < charArray.Length; i++)
{
    charArray[i] = defaultChar;
}
```

Or could be done like:

```
char[] charArray = Enumerable.Repeat<char>(defaultChar, length).ToArray();
```

You can also do the same using string constructor with `ToCharArray` like:

```
char[] charArray = new string(defaultChar, length).ToCharArray();
```

Comment: The first example is what this would look like in java.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private static char[] createCharArray(int length, char defaultChar)
{
    return new string(defaultChar, length).ToCharArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static char[] createCharArray(int length, char defaultChar)
{
    string ret = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        ret += defaultChar;
    return ret.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: This is an even worse way of making this `char[]` than the one in the OP. Granted, this'd be easier to translate to Java, but still...

Comment: haha yeah you are right, for some reason i got "string" stuck in my head when I saw new char[length]